# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

First I've added FirebaseAnalytics to my Android Unity project, and it works fine on the test. Then when I add FirebaseMessaging and build the app and send a message from my FireBase panel, The message will not show on the device/emulator and I get this error in Logcat :

> E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
>
> 1722-4448/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=pack_name (has extras) } U=0: not found
>
> E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.

There is a topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962566/error-while-delivering-the-message-serviceintent-not-found) that has no specific answer to the problem.

I followed FireBase [walkthrough](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client) to add FirebaseMessaging.unitypackage to my project and according to that I added these lines to my manifest :

```
<!-- The MessagingUnityPlayerActivity is a class that extends
     UnityPlayerActivity to work around a known issue when receiving
     notification data payloads in the background. -->
 <activity android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
 </activity>
 <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService" android:exported="false" />
```

P.S:

After Adding mentioned service in @jeevashankar answer to my manifest I get this error when a notif arrived :

> E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView - pack_name/com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity#0] query: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>       [SurfaceView - /com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity#0] connect: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>   E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView - pack_name/com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity#0]

**Update:**
I tested FirebaseMessaging in an empty Unity project and test it on emulator/device and it works till Android 7.1.1. But in Android 8 (API 26) and above makes this error and message will not be received :

> system_process E/NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=, channelId=null, id=0, tag=campaign_collapse_key_4015583716848879920, opPkg=, callingUid=10122, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10122, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)

Comment: If you are testing on Xiaomi, it is sometimes impossible to send messages, see this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109753/firebaseinstanceid-error-while-delivering-the-message-serviceintent-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
You need to import Analytics & Messaging plugins without PlayServiceResolver folder in them. Then download the last [unity-jar-resolver unity package from GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) and import it to your Unity project. After that just hit the Force Resolve button and get a successful operation message.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem:

> E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found

After some time, I found the solution by making the service exported in the manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".MyMessagingService"
    android:exported="true" 
    tools:ignore="ExportedService" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>

</service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) and add intent-filter with MESSAGING_EVENT action inside the Service in Android Manifest file.

```
<service android:name=".app.FireMsgService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

FireMsgService class extends the FirebaseMessagingService class &  inside the onMessageReceived method you will get notification messages .

```
public class FireMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);



            Log.v("Firebase MSG", ""+remoteMessage.getNotification().toString());



    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Unity Engine not android native. When I add mentioned service to the manifest , I get an error that I added to my post