# FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found into MI devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, mi

This error we found when the application is in the background for a long time. This issue I found into Xaiomi devices. I tested into Samsung it's running perfectly but in Xaiomi, it always throwing the same error.

Comment: There were lots of manufacturers in Android and they customized Android AOSP. So if it's device specific issue then really difficult to resolve. I have seen such issue earlier in one of my app.

Comment: Did you found anything, to resolved it?

Comment: No never and I put this in hold permanently because we  as a developer can't do anything. Yes there are patches available in market without any guarantee

Comment: I have also faced this issue, this occurs because when the user clears from a recent menu, MI force stops the application

Comment: Any solution? We are facing the same problem